# How to get the count of no of rows in multiple sheets of a workbook seperately?

Tags: function, excel-formula, count, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have 9 sheets in a workbook and in 10th sheet i created a column (say A) in which name of all the 9 sheets is mentioned.I applied the formula =CountMyRows(A2)-1 it returned the value of no of rows in sheet1 of my workbook.
But I don't know what miracle happened after that the same function didn't work.giving error #namevalue.
I googled the same but nothing helped.

Comment: CountMyRows is probably a User Defined Function. You could use the following to get the last row: `=LOOKUP(2,1/('Sheet1'!A:A<>""),ROW(A:A))` entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`

Comment: Yes it is user defined function.i run the following VBA code        
  Function CountMyRows(SName As String) As Long
    CountMyRows = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SName).UsedRange.Rows.Count
End Function.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is the same code is not running now..Function CountMyRows(SName) As Long         '# where SName is the name of a sheet
    Dim rowCount As Long
    rowCount = Worksheets(SName).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    CountMyRows = rowCount
End Function
Is there any problem in the code ?becoz now it's showing #value when applied

Comment: Hard to judge without knowing what's on the referenced sheet and how the sheet name is referenced, what you expect as a value in return.